# err: Could not run Puppet configuration client: execution expired

Tags: puppet

I am using puppet 2.6.1 for both master and slave on Ubuntu 10.

Client times out updating from master and returns the error:
err: Could not run Puppet configuration client: execution expired

This does not happen when there are not many files to update, however, when there are a lot the client times out.

Is there a way I can increase this timeout?

Answer (score 0):

You can crank up the timeout by adding `configtimeout = 600` or some other large number of seconds into the `[main]` section of `puppet.conf` to work around this.

The other answer of switching to Passenger for the HTTP server, as well as making other optimizations still apply though, as it should be quick enough that it doesn't need the timeout to be cranked up in that case.